# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'route' of undefined

Tags: javascript, api, service, maps, directions

I'm just starting out with Directions Service. I've hardcoded a couple of locations to make sure it's working. I keep getting the same error (Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'route' of undefined), and I can't figure out why. The code is almost an exact copy of the code from the documentation.

```html
    <script>
    var map;
    var directionsService;
    var directionsRenderer;

    function initMap() {
      var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
      var directionsRenderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();

      var chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(38.627003, -90.199402);
      var mapOptions = {
        zoom:10,
        center: chicago
      }
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
      directionsRenderer.setMap(map);
    }

    function calcRoute(start, end) {

      var request = {
        origin: "St Louis, MO",
        destination: "Chicago, IL",
        travelMode: 'DRIVING'
      };
        console.log(request);
      directionsService.route(request, function(result, status) {
        if (status == 'OK') {
          directionsRenderer.setDirections(result);
        }
      });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Could you correct the tags for your post? Your question is about Javascript but uses the HTML tag.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind! I figured it out. I was re-declaring directionService and directionRender inside initMap(), which changed the scope of those two variables! I changed it to the following below and it worked.

```js
    var map;
    var directionsService;
    var directionsRenderer;

    function initMap() {
      directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
      directionsRenderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
```